# Would you utilize strategy pattern here?

Tags: php, design-patterns

Is this code a good fit for the strategy pattern?

```
public function isValidEmail($email, $organization)
{   
    switch ($organization) {
        case 'USAF':
        case 'Army':
        case 'USMC':
        case 'Navy':
        case 'SOCOM':
            return (preg_match('/[.]mil$/i', $email) === 1);
            break;

        case 'Federal Gov.':
            return (preg_match('/[.]gov$/i', $email) === 1);
            break;

        case 'State/Local Gov.':
            $regionCollection = Mage::getModel('directory/region')
                ->getResourceCollection()
                ->addCountryFilter(array('US'))
                ->load();

            $stateAbbr = array();

            // Cycle through state abbreviations for match
            foreach ($regionCollection as $region) {
                $stateAbbr[] = strtolower($region->getCode());
            }
            $states = implode('|', $stateAbbr);

            return (preg_match("/[\.|@]{1}($states){1}\.us$/i", $email) ===
            break;

        case 'USCG':
        case 'DOD':
        case 'Defense Industry':
            return true;
            break;

        default:
            return false;
            break;
    }
    // It got past somehow?
    return false;
}
```

I was assuming you could have a simple interface to define a validate method but I'm slightly confused on how to handle the two odd ball cases in the switch statement that return true/false w/ no email logic.

```
interface ValidInterface
{
    public function isValid($email);
}
```

Comment: You don't need `break` after `return`.

Comment: Use `\.` instead of `[.]`. It's clearer, and more succinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track with your validator interface (I would name it something more meaningful like `EmailValidator`). You can then create a mapping of organizations to validators and look this up when performing the validation:

```
private $validators = array(
  'USAF' => new MilitaryEmailValidator(),
  'Army' => new MilitaryEmailValidator(),
  ...
  'Defense Industry' => new TrueEmailValidator()
);

public function isValidEmail($email, $organization) {
  if (isset($this->validators[$organization]))
    return $this->validators[$organization])->isValid($email);

  // default return
  return false;
}
```

Comment: How would your `TrueEmailValidator::isValid()` and `FalseEmailValidator::isValid()` methods look?  do they still conform to the interface and accept an `$email` parameter and then just ignore it and return true/false respectively?  This is the path I was initially headed down but was questioning this very specific approach to just ignoring those params.   Is this considered good practice?

Comment: @veilig: Yes, they would just ignore `$email`. There's nothing inherently wrong with this approach -- the whole idea of having an interface is that you don't care how it's implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I think the relevant design pattern here is Chain of Responsibility. It's essentially an object oriented version of the switch statement. You have a list (or tree) of objects. They each have the capability to determine if they should handle the issue (equivalent to the "case" statement). If they don't, the decision is passed on to the successors (the next "case" statement). You may or may not have a catch-all, equivalent to the "default:" statement.

Why then use Chain of Responsibility instead of a switch statement or the proposed map of string to object?

I submit that they are specific implementations that achieve the same thing. A more generic implementation may give you more degrees of freedom or type safety. The switch solution imposes very real practical limits on the amount of code you can put at each case / the number of cases you can reliably handle and maintain. Case in point: in your code the branch for state/gov is quite complex, and putting that in an object or a method would clean up the code considerable.

Comment: I am sorry to say but _Chain of Responsibility_ is not relevant here

Comment: Care to expand on why you think so? It's the general solution to this kind of problem, but may be overkill for the reasons that I state.